# three.js scene.remove() deletes the object from memory

Tags: javascript, caching, three.js, gltf

I'm currently working with streaming a LOD'ed scene more than 5000 mesh chunks. These are loaded as you need them (see them), and it works wonderly. But to minimize the data needed to stream I'm implementing a timed- and spatial cache functionality, caching the chunks that are close to me and have recently been fetched. Each cached chunk is a scene containing a set of children geometricaly describing the chunk. And when I render the scene I identify the chunks needed to be renderd, and I put each chunks children in a scene object, and add that scene to the main scene. This to be able to clear the previous children by removing one object.

```
foreach (chunk I see) {
   foreach (child in chunk) {
      containerScene.add(child);
   }
}

mainScene.add(containerScene);
```

But my problem is that after I've removed the containerScene from the mainScene using remove() the cached chunk scenes children are deleted from the memory, removing the cached scenes children.

```
chunk.children.length == x

mainScene.remove(containerScene);

// the cached chunks looses their children when containerScene 
// is removed the om m
chunk.children.length == 0
```

I solved it by adding a clone of each children through

```
containerScene.add(chunk.child.clone(true));
```

but doing this each time for all children to be rendered every time a child is added or removed is probably not plausible.

Is there a better way to do this, allowing me to easy remove and add objects to the scene, without the need to reload my cache each time?

Comment: In that 2nd code block, are you sure chunk.children.length == x? It would seem that in the 1st code block, containerScene.add(child) should cause 'child' to be removed from its parent 'chunk'. i.e., I would expect chunk.children.length == 0 by the time the code reaches mainScene.add(containerScene).

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice it at first, but as I understood how it worked, i managed to get it working.